# Qt Designer plugin install issue

Tags: qt, plugins, installation, qt-designer, qt5.5

Just reinstalled Qt from qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.3-online.exe (5.5 and 5.6 versions for MSVC 2013, 32 and 64 bit). My custom Qt Designer plugin stopped to install into C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\plugins\designer directory. Worked fine previously with qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.2-online.exe and Qt 5.5. Trying to set QT_PLUGIN_PATH explicitly which was unnecessary previously - does not work as well. What could be wrong here? pro file unchanged is:

```
CONFIG      += plugin debug_and_release
TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget(WidgetBoxPlugin)
TEMPLATE    = lib

HEADERS     = widgetboxplugin.h widgetbox.h \
              widgetboxextensionfactory.h \
              widgetboxdesignercontainerextension.h
SOURCES     = widgetboxplugin.cpp widgetbox.cpp \
              widgetboxextensionfactory.cpp \
              widgetboxdesignercontainerextension.cpp
RESOURCES   = icons.qrc
LIBS        += -L.

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += designer
} else {
    CONFIG += designer
}

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
INSTALLS    += target
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `install` to make arguments in Project Configuration in Qt Creator